# Creating Drive Time Polygons In ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.5, drive-time-areas

I have a feature set of locations, made up of several points.

I have the Network Analyst extension for ArcMap, and a feature set of all the streets in the area I'm looking at.

How can I create drive time polygons (polygons of the areas I can reach, for each point feature, within a certain number of minutes) using these tools?

So far I've only found tutorials for doing this with the Business Analyst extension, which I do not have and is not available on MyESRI.

Comment: first you have to create a network dataset based on your street data - see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm

Comment: It might help your search to know that another term for "drive time polygons" is "isochrone polygons."

Comment: Once you have a network dataset, there are three steps in ArcMap: create a "service area analysis layer" with your desired time, add locations to the service area layer, and solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating info from the comments --

First you have to create a network dataset based on your street data - see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm

Once you have a network dataset, there are three steps in ArcMap: create a "service area analysis layer" with your desired time, add locations to the service area layer, and solve.

Detailed instructions here:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-service-area-layer.htm